# jaxbUnmarshaller stucked while passing stream

Tags: java, sockets, stream, server

i have a problem with unmarshaller of xml file. I wrote client and server program:
Client:

```
    public void run(){

    try(Socket skt = new Socket(host,port);
        PrintStream Output = new PrintStream(skt.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader Input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream())))
    {

        Output.println("NAME");
        String buf=Input.readLine();
        app.setNameLbl(buf);

        Output.println("RAMTOTAL");
        buf=Input.readLine();
        ramTotal=Integer.parseInt(buf);
        app.getRamTotalLbl().setText(buf+" MB");
        app.getRamBar().setMaximum(ramTotal);

        Status status;
        Output.println("STATUS");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Status.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        status =(Status) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(Input);//<--- here
        System.out.println(status.getTemp());
        while(status!=null){
            app.getRamBar().setValue((int)((ramTotal-status.getRamAvailable())*100)/1024);
            app.getTempBar().setValue((int)Math.round(status.getTemp()));
            app.getTempBar().setString(String.valueOf(status.getTemp())+"'C");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(String x : status.getPplLogged()){
                sb.append(x);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            app.getLoggedUsersArea().setText(sb.toString());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Output.println("STATUS");
            status = (Status) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( Input );
        }
    }
```

And server:

```
    public ResponseThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ResponseThread");
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true))
    {

        String inputLine ;     
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if(inputLine.equals("STATUS")){
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Status.class);
                Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

                status.update();
                StringWriter dataWriter = new StringWriter();
                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(status, dataWriter); 
                out.print(dataWriter.toString());
                out.println();
                out.flush();

            }
            else if(inputLine.equals("NAME")){                  
                out.println(StaticActions.getName());
            }
            else if(inputLine.equals("RAMTOTAL")){
                out.println(StaticActions.getRamTotal());
            }
            else if(inputLine.equals("RESET")){
                StaticActions.rebootPi();
            }
            else if(inputLine.equals("TEST")){
                out.println("OK");
            }
        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException | JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Main problem is that it stucks in place where i marked it. I think that it is waiting for EOF mark. But i do not know how to pass it .
Please help me with this problem. 
Have a nice day!